# Как изменить форму в TextView?

Tags: android

Как сделать TextView Круглой? без использования картинки и без использования xml drawable(shape)?

Может есть на гитхабе такой спец компонент?

Просто дело в том что у меня точень много картинок в drawable 9 png. А в приложении должно быть 100 кругов разных цветов. А для каждого TextView создавать отдельный круг с отдельным цветом это ужас.

Жалко что нет способа чтобы создать в drawable используя xml форму круга, а уже в textView указать цвет backgrounda, так как если в TextView добавить поле BackGround XML то для цвета там поля уже не будет....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете написать кастомный класс - наследник `TextView`, переопределив в нем метод отрисовки бэкграунда и добавив метод для установки цвета.

Примерно так. Назовем наш класс `CircleTextView`:

```
package com.customwidget.app;

public class CircleTextView extends TextView {

    private int defaultColor = Color.GREEN;
    private int mCenterX;
    private int mCenterY;
    private int mRadius;
    private Paint mPaint;


    public CircleTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CircleTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawCircle(mCenterX, mCenterY, mRadius, mPaint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int size = Math.max(height, width);
        mCenterX = mCenterY = mRadius = size/2;
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);

    }

    public void setColorBackground(int color) {
        defaultColor = color;
        mPaint.setColor(defaultColor);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    private void init() {

        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        setColorBackground(defaultColor);
    }

}
```

Использование:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CircleTextView textView = (CircleTextView) findViewById(R.id.circleTextView2);
        textView.setColorBackground(Color.BLUE);


    }
}
```

Разметка activity_main.xml:

```
<com.customwidget.app.CircleTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/circleTextView"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<com.customwidget.app.CircleTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/circleTextView2"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />
```

Результат:

[image: screen]